# Flow: What is the equivalent of PropTypes.func in flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-proptypes

I am trying to migrate from `PropTypes` to `Flow` type checking in my React components.

Please what is the equivalent of `PropTypes.func` in `Flow`, to specify that a prop is a Function ?

My code looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

type Props = {
  doSomething: /* function */
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
type Props = {
  doSomething: () => void,
}
```

or specify arguments if needed.

Answer (score 5):

There is a clearer way:

```
type Props = {
  doSomething: Function // with capital letter
}
```

Comment: From [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-function-type): "`Function` has become an alias to any and will be deprecated and removed in a future version of Flow"